# Website ruined when resized

Tags: html, css

So after working my behind off all day at my website, I find out that it's basically only compatible on my computer on 1920*1080.

I suppose that I'm to ''glue'' objects somehow to x areas of the website but I don't know how to.

I know this is not exactly a direct question but can you please tell me what is causing my website to go out of order when resized? Here is the whole website JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vuz2L/

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

    <head>
        <title>Heilsa</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<img id="bordi" src="heilsa2.png"/>
<div id="bigtext"><a href="heim.html">Heilsa</a></div>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="heim.html">Heim</a></li> <span id="menubord">
    <li><a href="sida1.html">Hollt Mataræði</a></li>
    <li><a href="sida2.html">Reynslusögur</a></li> </span>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="block">
        </div>
        <div id="meginmal">
        <h1>Fyrirsögn</h1>
        <p>ch-slahing thust get a proper bitch-slapping to stop making walls of text, but if you are weird then thaA wall of text is something thust get a proper bitch-slapping to stop making walls of text, but if you are weird then that doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some othA wall of text is something thust get a proper bitch-slapping to stop making walls of text, but if you are weird then that doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some othA wall of text is something thust get a proper bitch-slapping to stop making walls of text, but if you are weird then that doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some otht doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some otht doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some othoesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some othsome other things that would work but will take hours to think of. People are considered a nuisance if they create walls of text. This might be the end. If you hope this is the end, I am not sure. But if I was not sure then I wouldn't be talking. I should know. Or should I? The best way to make a better and good wall of text is to copy and paste what you previously typed or write. Hey, that reminds me. Walls of text aren't always on the internet! They could be anywhere that is able to produce symbols. D'oh. A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. Actually not really lame. You can created a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text. So basically, no one except God and Al Gore knows when or where or how the wall of text existed/was invented. Noobs probably invented, but probably not. Who knows. Walls of texts are usually filled with a lot of useless information and junk. Information and junk can be the same, but only if the information is junk or the junk is information.A wall of text is something thust get a proper bitch-slapping to stop making walls of text, but if you are weird then that doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some other things that would work but will take hours to think of. People are considered a nuisance if they create walls of text. This might be the end. If you hope this is the end, I am not sure. But if I was not sure then I wouldn't be talking. I should know. Or should I? The best way to make a better and good wall of text is to copy and paste what you previously typed or write. Hey, that reminds me. Walls of text aren't always on the internet! They could be anywhere that is able to produce symbols. D'oh. A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. Actually not really lame. You can created a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text. So basically, no one except God and Al Gore knows when or where or how the wall of text existed/was invented. Noobs probably invented, but probably not. Who knows. Walls of texts are usually filled with a lot of useless information and junk. Information and junk can be the same, but only if the information is junk or the junk is information.
        </p>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="push">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
     <img id="undir" src="undir.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

And CSS:

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

#container {
   min-height:100%;
   height: auto !important;
   position:relative;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -232px;
   }

.menu {
width:700px;
height:180px;
font-family:Trajan Pro;
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:3px 2px 3px #333333;
margin-left:1010px;
position:absolute;
top:135px;
}
#menubord {

}
.menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
}
.menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color:red;
font-weight:600;
font-size: 22px;
letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}

.menu a:hover {
text-shadow: 8px 5px 8px #333333;
font-size:24px;
animation-name: opac;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-play-state: running;
/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name: opac;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes opac
{
0%   {opacity:1}
25%  {opacity:0.5}
50%  {opacity:0.1}
75%  {opacity:0.5}
100% {opacity:1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes opac /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {opacity:1}
25%  {opacity:0.5}
50%  {opacity:0.1}
75%  {opacity:0.5}
100% {opacity:1}
}

.menu a:active {
text-shadow: 12px 8px 12px #333333;
}

#content {
min-height:100%;
position: relative;
width: 800  px;
height: 800px;
margin-right:200px;
margin-left:200px;
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}



#block1 { /*IGNORE THIS. I AM SAVING IT FOR LATER*/
    background: red;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20); /* IE */
    -moz-opacity:0.2; /* Mozilla */
    opacity: 0.2; /* CSS3 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%; width:100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin:10px;
}

#meginmal {
padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size:20px;
border-right: solid;
border-left: solid;
font-family: Trajan Pro;
}

#bordi {
height:100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
  }



#wrapper {

   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:232px;   /* Height of the footer */
   margin-top:200px;
}

.push {
height: 232px;
}

#bigtext {
z-index:1;
margin-top:-300px;
margin-left:700px;
position: absolute;
font-size:70px;
font-family: Trajan Pro;

}
#bigtext a {
text-decoration: none;
color:black;
border-bottom:solid;
border-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0);
}

#bigtext a:hover{
animation-name: big;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-play-state: running;
/* Safari and Chrome: */
-webkit-animation-name: big;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes big
{
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    50% { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    100%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes big /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    0%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
    50% { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }
    100%   { border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all.

When do developers use margin and padding and how do they make sure they don't ruin their web page in other resolutions?

EDIT: I notice that my question got down voted like pretty much all my questions on this board. I gotta ask, what the hell is wrong with people on this website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you trying to design website try not to use fixed values like X px, when X is large number, like width: 800 px;.

for example if you change #content to this:

```
#content {
min-height:100%;
position: relative;
width: 800 px;
height: 800px;
margin-right:5%;
margin-left:5%;
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:60px;
/* Height of the footer */
}
```

where i changed

```
margin-right:5%;
margin-left:5%;
```

the main content is becoming more likely.

Try avoid big fixed values, changing them to percentable values, or align: left;, etc

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of margin-left + position:absolute values which breaks the layout. Instead of using absolute positioning, try to use margins and floats, or even browser natural flow of displaying elements in the page.